# Touchpad not responding to double-tap to click

Tags: kubuntu, touchpad, hp-touchpad

I have an HP laptop on which I installed Kubuntu 19.10 (Plasmashell 5.16.5).

I can use the touchpad just fine to move the cursor and click using the touchpad's buttons. However, I cannot click by double-tapping as I would using Windows.

Is there any particular software I need to install for this to work?

Comment: When you open *System Settings > Input Devices > Touchpad*, do you see "touchpad not found" and are all the settings in any tab there all greyed out?

Comment: @JusticeforMonica thanks for pointing me in the right direction! There was a Tap-to-click setting that was not enabled by default. That sorted me out.

Comment: Please post an answer preferably with an image. That will be of use to other users. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing ... Please always mention the specific version of Kubuntu and the output of `plasmashell --version`. The latter is meaningful because of the possibility that users may or may not have added the [kubuntu-backports ppa](https://launchpad.net/~kubuntu-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports) for bug fixes and possibly newer software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, I had to go into System Settings, then select Input Devices from the left, and finally Touchpad. The Tap-to-click option was what I needed to enable.

[image]